# .NET Core Web API push to Apple/Android push notification servers

Tags: android, asp.net-core, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, signalr

I have Chat service in .NET Core Web API, handling chat messages through Signal R when clients are online.

Also, i have mobile clients (android/apple) and i need to handle messages sent when client is in offline mode. I am aware if clients are offline/online. So, when the client is offline, i want to send message to apple/android push notification server so it can notify the device about new message(s).

Which options do i have to connect net core Web API to android/apple push notification servers? Any experiences with sending client push notifications to mobile clients from .net service?

Answer (score 4):

### Use CorePush lib

It's very lightweight. I use it across all my projects to send Firebase **Android** and Apple **iOS** push notifications. Useful links:

1. [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CorePush/)
2. [Documentation](https://github.com/andrei-m-code/net-core-push-notifications)

The interface is very simple and minimalistic:

**Send APN message**:

```
var apn = new ApnSender(settings, httpClient);
await apn.SendAsync(notification, deviceToken);
```

**Send FCM message**:

```
var fcm = new FcmSender(settings, httpClient);
await fcm.SendAsync(deviceToken, notification);
```

Comment: THE samples and docs are rubbish of it doesnt even show you how to get tokens or nothing

Comment: @csharpdude77 well they don't have to. The docs are for the library, not for the firebase or apn or Apple/Android push notification subscription.

Comment: @Andrei how to subscribe to topic using this package, how to create group using this package?

Answer (score 1):

You need To make a POST request to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send with the following parameters
**Header**

- *Authorization:* `key=YOUR_SERVER_KEY`
- *Content-Type:* `Application/JSON`

**Body:**

```
{
 "to" : "YOUR_FCM_TOKEN_WILL_BE_HERE",
 "collapse_key" : "type_a",
 "notification" : {
     "body" : "First Notification",
     "title": "Collapsing A"
 },
 "data" : {
     "body" : "First Notification",
     "title": "Collapsing A",
     "key_1" : "Data for key one",
     "key_2" : "Hellowww"
 }
```

You can get your server Token from `Firebase Console`. Also you need to [set up APN](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs) in order for this to work on iOS.
You can find More info [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use any cloud solutions for this case, like Azure Notification Hub.

You can check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/) and configure your app with Notification Hub. With default configuration you will be able to broadcast your notification to all registered devices.

But in your case you need to send a notification to a specific device. In this case you need to use tags. When you register the device with Notification Hub register it with an unique id. So when you send a notification send it with same unique id as tag and it will received by that device only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pusher](https://pusher.com). It is a platform which simplifies working with push notifications. Currently it supports Android, iOS and channel-based notifications and, in my view, it's easy to configure than Azure Notifications or Amazon SNS.

Comment: thx, too bad we have to pay for it for the enterprise usage :)

Answer (score 0):

I’pretty late in this discussion, but it might still help someone having the same question:

- Offline Push Notifications: We did this once as a combination of regular/online push notifications and local notifications. So, the idea is to synchronize the next N scheduled notifications to the client and then send local notifications directly on the client. Of course, tjis scenario does not work for all business cases.
- Regular Push Notifications: We’re sending push requests using our own library, https://www.nuget.org/packages/PushNotifications.Server.AspNetCore/ which perfectly integrates with both, Android/FCM and Apple/APNS. Read the readme to get a first impression of the API.